# Figuring out which direction my object is facing on a 2D plane?

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, game-physics

My friend and I were messing around in XNA 4.0 making a 2D racing game. Kind of like this one: Ivan “Ironman” Stewart’s Super Off Road. The problem we are having is know which direction are car is facing to move it appropriately. We could track the direction by a enum value North, South, East, West but we don't want to do that for a number of reasons.

We were wondering if there was a way to accomplish this via math. Maybe by having an anchor point designated at the hood of the car and having the car always move towards that spot and then move that anchor point. We aren't sure. Or maybe there is a way using a 2D Vector.

I figured since we hit a hard spot, we should ask the coding community for help!

Just to be clear. I'm not looking for code; I just want to discuss some concepts of 2D movement in all directions without having to track a direction enum. I know that can't be the only way to do it.

Comment: consider keeping track of movement using 2d vectors, i.e [3,4] might mean that in any given second, an object would travel 3 units vertically, and 4 units horizontally (=5 units @ ~35 degrees)

Comment: be sure to post this over at [gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com) as well.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice guys! stackoverflow never fails!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Car physics is actually a very difficult subject. I wish you well, but your're embarking on a difficult quest.

As for the answer: you can store the direction angle in radians and use atan2 function to get the relation between angles.

Or you can use Vector2D and use vector math to determine angles, also atan2 will be your friend.

Asnippets of my code on the issue:

```
public class RotatingImage implements RotatingImageVO {
  protected double x, y; // center position
  protected double facingx, facingy;
  protected double angle;

  protected void calculateAngle() {
    angle = Math.atan2(x-facingx, facingy-y);
  }
}
```

Remember that calculating atan2 is expensive. When I did it for each draw iteration for each object (tower defense, towers were rotating;) it took ~30% of my computing power. Do it only if you detect a noticable angle change. Like this:

```
public void setFacingPoint(double facingx, double facingy) {
  if (Math.abs((facingx-this.facingx)/(facingx+this.facingx)) > 0.002 
      || Math.abs((facingy-this.facingy)/(facingy+this.facingy)) > 0.002) {
    this.facingx = facingx;
    this.facingy = facingy;
    calculateAngle();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Describing the direction using a unitvector and the position using a point makes sense. Then when the car moves forward you do

`currentPosition = currentPosition + distance * directionvector;` // (pseudocode)

When changing the direction it is good to use a matrix to (rotate)transform the direction vector.

(I'm not familiar with XNA)

Wrote some dummy code to illustrate:

```
[Test]
public void MoveForwardTest()
{
    var position = new Point(0, 0);
    var direction = new Vector(1, 0);
    double distance = 5;
    //Update position moving forward distance along direction
    position = position + distance * direction; 
    Assert.AreEqual(5.0, position.X, 1e-3);
    Assert.AreEqual(0, position.Y, 1e-3);
}

[Test]
public void RotateThenMoveTest()
{
    var position = new Point(0, 0);
    var direction = new Vector(1, 0);
    double distance = 5;
    //Create the rotation matrix
    var rotateTransform = new RotateTransform(90); 
    //Apply the rotation to the direction
    direction = Vector.Multiply(direction, rotateTransform.Value); 
    //Update position moving forward distance along direction
    position = position + distance * direction; 
    Assert.AreEqual(0, position.X, 1e-3);
    Assert.AreEqual(5.0, position.Y, 1e-3);
}

[Test]
public void CheckIfOtherCarIsInfrontTest()
{
    var position = new Point(0, 0);
    var direction = new Vector(1, 0);
    var otherCarPosition = new Point(1, 0);
    //Create a vector from current car to other car
    Vector vectorTo = Point.Subtract(otherCarPosition, position); 
    //If the dotproduct is > 0 the other car is in front
    Assert.IsTrue(Vector.Multiply(direction, vectorTo) > 0); 
}

[Test]
public void AngleToNortTest()
{
    var direction = new Vector(1, 0);
    var northDirection = new Vector(0, 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(90, Vector.AngleBetween(direction, northDirection), 1e-3);
}
```

Comment: Magic man, how do you add a double to a vector/point? And do you mean to:(position + distance) * direction; OR position + (distance * direction); ?

Comment: The latter, I was a little bored so I coded up some dummies in code. hope I got them right :)

Answer (score 0):

You can represent the direction by using a normalized vector. This is just a hard coded example but you could easily use the input from a gamepad thumbstick.

```
Vector2 north = new Vector2(0, -1);
```

And later in your code move your sprite like this (assuming there is a position vector).

```
float speed = 100; // 100 pixels per second.
Vector2 direction = north;
position += direction * ((float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds * speed);
```